# How to make minitest available in ruby module

Tags: ruby, capybara, minitest, assertions

I am trying to make a module that has a bunch of helper definitions. Some of the defs use assert from Minitest::Assertions. How can i get access to these assertions inside a module. Mock example below

```
module Helper
  require 'minitest'

  TEST = Minitest::Assertions

  module Helper::Scripts
    def self.assertion
       TEST.assert true 
    end
  end
end

Helper::Scripts.assertion #undefined assert
```

Comment: What are you trying to achive?

Comment: @Зелёный I want to have a wrapper module for all my "helper" defintions that i have lying around. Doesn't necessarily belong in a class as they help the entire app. example: Helper::Move.scroll_element_offset({params})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define an instance accessor named `assertions`

```
module TestHelpers
  include Minitest::Assertions

  # Number of assertions executed in this run
  attr_accessor :assertions

  def assert_true
    self.assertions = 0

    assert true
  end
end
```

We can use TestHelpers this way:

```
class FooTest
  include TestHelpers
end

test = FooTest.new
test.assert_true #=> true
```